# AdjustPan calculation

Tags: android, keyboard

I have a view in top of the screen which I want to always be displayed (In every device, even if keyboard is opened). The problem is that in the middle of the screen I have an EditText. In some devices, if the EditText gains focus, the keyboard opens and causes layout to move upward. I do not want to use AdjustResize which will cause background image to stretch. Is it possible to know if a layout was moved or not because of keyboard being opened? Also, how does this upward movement been calculated? I am thinking about reposition the view whenever is needed

-First attempt to solve the problem: I have tried Coordinator layout. I did not find a behavior to do what i want, so i tried to implement my own behavior. I added a space view in the bottom of the layout and whenever this view changed its position i tried to translate downward the top view. But even if layoutDependsOn() returns true the onDependentViewChanged() is not called in order to calculate the translation.

-Second attempt to solve the problem: I added again a space view in the bottom of the layout. Also, I Added an onGlobalLayoutListener in order to track if the keyboard was opened. If so, i tried to calculate space view's position and compare it with its previous position in order to move downward the top view.

-Third attempt was to use AdjustNothing and hand by myself the translations of the views that need to reposition theirselves on keyboard open. This was the only attempt that gave me some results, but seems buggy and in the future i am sure that will cause much more problems than it solves.

In addition, i found that x, y, translationX, translationY do not change in adjustPan. The only way to calculate the correct position is to use getLocationOnScreen(). But this is possible after the view was laid out. Can we calculate it before the view is laid out?

Answer (score 2):

For future reference, in order to calculate the pixels of upward translation in AdjustPan mode you must do something like the following code. Basically, in AdjustPan we push as much as is needed the layout in order to make the focused EditText fully visible.

```
val rect = Rect()
constraintLayout.getWindowVisibleDisplayFrame(rect)
val editTextGlobalRect = Rect()
view.getGlobalVisibleRect(editTextGlobalRect)

//if it is true the editText will be hidden so the layout will be moved upwards due to adjust pan
val translation = if (editTextGlobalRect.bottom > visibleArea.bottom) {
    //Calculate how much the layout is going to be pushed
    editTextGlobalRect.bottom - visibleArea.bottom.toFloat()
} else {
    0f
}
```

Also, if you want to calculate the new position of the view, in order to stick in the same screen position, you must do something like that:

```
val stationaryViewGlobalRect = Rect()
stationaryView.getGlobalVisibleRect(stationaryViewGlobalRect)

stationaryView.y = when {
    translation <= stationaryViewGlobalRect.top -> {
        //Stationary view is not hidden at all but it was moved upwards
        stationaryViewGlobalRect.top - translation + resources.getDimension(R.dimen.stationary_view_margin_top)
    }
    translation <= stationaryViewGlobalRect.bottom -> {
        //Stationary view is not fully hidden
        translation + (stationaryViewGlobalRect.bottom - translation)
    }
    else -> translation + stationaryViewGlobalRect.top //Stationary view is fully hidden
}
```

Comment: The above makes sense, but how are the values for `visibleArea` derived?